# getting the cell count of an excel sheet with a filter - Error When the first character is an equals or a minus sign, Excel thinks it's a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the cell count from an excel sheet depending on the filter I add, so that I can get different cell counts depending on the filters.

I have the following formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Cybersecurity!A1:A208,ROW(Cybersecurity!F1:F208)-MIN(ROW(Cybersecurity!F1:F208)),,1)), --( Cybersecurity!F1:F208="Name"))
```

However when I insert this in the cell, I am getting an error :=

```
When the first character is an equals or a minus sign, Excel thinks it's a formula
```

I checked my locale settings and its accepting the comma sign.

Can I change it in a way that Excel can accept this formula?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

Use singel tik `'` character to make string value before type *Excel formula character* as a cell value.
For Example :
`-Some string value` add singel tik `'-some string value`

Comment: I want a formula not string value

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was a setting in the Control Panel -> Region settings.  Change date, time or number formats. Click on the Advanced Settings Tab, in the Decimal Symbol I had a comma (,) and I changed it to a (.)  That solved my problem